# How many coroutines is too many?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I need to speed up a search over some collection with millions of elements. 
Search predicate needs to be passed as argument.

I have been wondering wether the simplest solution(at least for now) wouldn't be just using coroutines for the task.

The question I am facing right now is how many coroutines can I actually create at once. :D As a side note there might be more than one such search running concurrently.

Can I make millions of coroutines(one for every item) for every such search? Should I decide on some workload per coroutine(for example 1000 items per coroutine)? Should I also decide on some cap for coroutines amount?

I have rough understanding of coroutines and how they actually work, however, I have no idea what are the performance limitations of this feature.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're on the JVM, you could just use a parallell stream. Something like `list.parallelStream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Comment: If you're going to be doing lots of searches, wouldn't it be much more efficient to sort the collection (and/or add one or more indexes), to avoid having to scan the whole collection each time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The memory weight of a coroutine scales with the depth of the call trace from the coroutine builder block to the suspension point. Each `suspend fun` call adds another `Continuation` object to a linked list and this is retained while the coroutine is suspended. A rough figure for one `Continuation` instance is 100 bytes.

So, if you have a call trace depth of, say, 5, that amounts to 500 bytes per item. A million items is 500 MB.

However, unless your search code involves blocking operations that would leave a thread idle, you aren't gaining anything from coroutines. Your task looks more like an instance of *data paralellism* and you can solve it very efficiently using the `java.util.stream` API (as noted by user [marstran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137489) in the comment).

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't answer directly my question but provides the actual information I needed.

Answer (score 0):

According the [kotlin coroutine starter guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#coroutines-are-light-weight), the example launches 100K coroutines. I believe what you intend to do is exactly what kotlin coroutine is designed for.

Answer (score 0):

If you will not do many modifications over your collection then just store it in a HashMap,
else store it in a TreeMap. Then just search items there. I believe the search methods implemented there are optimized enough to handle a million items in a blink. I would not use coroutines in this case.

Documentation (for Kotlin):

HashMap: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/HashMap

TreeMap: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/TreeMap